# Show last checked + two more (from array)

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have questionnaire of 20 checkboxes pulled from a JSON file into an array.

When an item is checked I push the question value to an array [1,3] that also stores in a cookie – so when the user returns, questions 1 + 3 remain checked.

```
var questions = ["1", "2", "3" ... "20"];

jQuery(this).change(function() {
    var question_value = jQuery(this).val();

    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        Cookies.set('completed', questions_completed);
        questions_completed.push(question_value);
    } else {
        // splice/remove the item from the array    
    }
});

var questions_completed = [1, 3]; // stores checked/completed questions number
```

What I want to do is show 3 checkboxes at a time (not all 20).

The last question appears at the top (checked) and then two more from the list (not checked) until all questions are completed.

I can't figure out how to approach this correctly – I need to compare the completed array with the questions array, but I can't seem to do this within creating multiple loops within loops.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show your current implementation so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the unanswered questions you can use the difference of the two arrays like the following:

```js
let questions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let answered = [1, 5, 6, 9];

function getUnansweredQuestions(n = 3){
  let unanswered = questions.filter(x => !answered.includes(x));
  
  if(typeof n == "number" && n > 0){
    unanswered = unanswered.slice(0, n);
  }
  
  return unanswered;
}

console.log(getUnansweredQuestions());
```

To get the last answered question and the next two non-answered you can save the last answered question and add this to the non-answered:

```js
let last_answered = null;

jQuery(this).change(function() {
    var question_value = jQuery(this).val();
    // ...
    last_answered = question_value;
});

let questions = getUnansweredQuestions(2).push(last_answered);
```

Note that if you want to keep track of the order when the user unchecks one of your questions, use an array instad of one value `last_answered`. Then you can add the questions in the order they are answered. (At the moment your `questions_completed` is exactly that, if you don't change the order. This means you can simply use `questions_completed[-1]` or `questions_completed[questions_completed.length - 1]` to ghet the last answered question.)

With this you seem to be able to make your question form:

```js
let json_questions = {1: "A?", 2: "B?", 3: "C?", 4: "D?", 5: "E?", 6: "F?", 7: "G?"}
let questions = Object.keys(json_questions);
let answered = [];
let questions_completed = [];

function getUnansweredQuestions(n){
  let unanswered = questions.filter(x => !questions_completed.includes(x));
  
  if(typeof n == "number" && n > 0){
    unanswered = unanswered.slice(0, n);
  }
  
  return unanswered;
}

function createQuestion(id, label, value, checked){
  return ("<div class='question'>" + 
      "<label for='" + id + "'>" + 
        label + 
      "</label>" + 
      "<input " + 
        "value='" + value + "' " + 
        "type='checkbox' " + 
        "id='" + id + "' " + 
        "class='question' " + 
        (checked ? " checked='checked'" : "") + 
        " />" + 
    "</div>");
}

function createQuestions(){
  let n = 3;
  let html = "";
  if(questions_completed.length > 0){
    let last = questions_completed[questions_completed.length - 1];
    html += createQuestion(last, json_questions[last], last, true);
    n--;
  }
  
  let ask = getUnansweredQuestions(n);
  for(let i = 0; i < ask.length; i++){
    html += createQuestion(ask[i], json_questions[ask[i]], ask[i], false);
  }
  
  $(".questions").html(html);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change", ".question", function(){
      var question_value = $(this).val();
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          // Cookies.set('completed', questions_completed);
          questions_completed.push(question_value);
      } else {
        let i = questions_completed.indexOf(question_value);
        if(i >= 0){
          questions_completed.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    createQuestions();
  });
  createQuestions();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions"></div>
```